# How to read the entries in an editable pdf using pdfminer, pypdf2 or any pdf mining python library?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer, pypdf

Using pdfminer

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import BytesIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
     rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
     retstr = BytesIO()
     codec = 'utf-8'
     laparams = LAParams()
     device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
     fp = open(path, 'rb')
     interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
     password = ""
     maxpages = 0
     caching = True
     pagenos=set()

     for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
    interpreter.process_page(page)

     text = retstr.getvalue()

fp.close()
device.close()
retstr.close()
return text
```

Using PyPDF2

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('85-0430EBallastWater.pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
out = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pdfReader.numPages
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)          #'9' is the page number
output = pageObj.extractText()
```

But even after trying with two of the APIs I get the pdf harcoded values but not the values in the empty boxes which is the editable part of pdf ?

Example :- Vessel name : salil

I was able to read the 'Vessel name :' but instead of salil i get '' empty string. The point is to be able to read salil.

Below is the pdf which i want to parse, kindly help.

[image: This the editable pdf example]